# Converting column data to row

Tags: t-sql

There has to be a simpler way to do this, right? I have 100 rows of numeric values, and I want the first row to be in a new table, row 1 column A, second row to be in the new table, row 1 column B, ... 100th row to be in the new table, row 100 column J. Just for fun, I'm also writing a single letter based on that numeric value into the new table, instead of a numeric. So here's my code:

```
UPDATE #data
SET Block = CASE OStatus WHEN 1 THEN 'C' WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'D' WHEN 4 THEN 'S' WHEN 5 THEN 'P' ELSE '' END

DECLARE  @Ax NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Bx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Cx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Dx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Ex NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Fx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Gx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Hx NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Ix NVARCHAR(1)
    ,@Jx NVARCHAR(1)

SET @Count1 = 0
WHILE @Count1 < 10 BEGIN
SET @Count1 += 1

SELECT @Ax = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 +  0
SELECT @Bx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 10
SELECT @Cx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 20
SELECT @Dx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 30
SELECT @Ex = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 40
SELECT @Fx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 50
SELECT @Gx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 60
SELECT @Hx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 70
SELECT @Ix = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 80
SELECT @Jx = Block FROM #data WHERE ID = @Count1 + 90

INSERT INTO _dbh_grid
 SELECT
 @Ax,@Bx,@Cx,@Dx,@Ex,@Fx,@Gx,@Hx,@Ix,@Jx

END
```

Comment: Sorry, fixed the select statements. They were giving a transposed version of what I wanted.

Comment: I saw a way to dramatically cut down on the case statements by adding another column to my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the PIVOT functionality (and a little math) to make it work; you could probably make it dynamic.

```
/*build a sample data set*/

SELECT TOP 100
        column_id AS OSStatus
      , ID = IDENTITY( INT, 1,1)
INTO    #data
FROM    sys.columns
WHERE   column_id < 6;

SELECT *
FROM #data d;


/*break the data set into groups of 10, and identify the ordinal position within each group
column_postition returns group
row_position returns ordinal within group
*/
WITH    c AS ( SELECT   OSStatus
                      , column_position = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID )
                                            - 1 ) / 10
                      , row_position = ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) - 1 )
                        % 10
               FROM     #data
             )
    SELECT  [A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F], [G], [H], [I], [J]

    FROM    ( SELECT    c.OSStatus
                      , column_name = CHAR(65 + c.column_position) --convert to a-J
                      , c.row_position
              FROM      c
            ) p
    PIVOT
        (MIN(OsStatus)
         FOR column_name
         IN ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F], [G], [H], [I], [J])
         ) pvt


DROP TABLE #data;
```

Comment: That's pretty impressive, thanks. I had thought about pivot tables but couldn't wrap my mind around how to do them. This is extremely helpful.